# Excel get_range

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How can I use Excel `get_range` to put the following data into a range value.

I believe I should be able to use `get_range` to do this, I'm just not sure how.

Columns

```
C1 = name, 
C5 = value, 
C10 = value
```

Answer (score 5):

I assumed you wanted these in the column headings. If not, change the cell reference in get_Range(). The following will do it:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Range targetRange = targetSheet.get_Range("A1");
targetRange.Value = name;
Excel.Range targetRange = targetSheet.get_Range("E1");
targetRange.Value = value;
Excel.Range targetRange = targetSheet.get_Range("J1");
targetRange.Value = value;
```

If you don't have any content between A1 and J1 that you want to keep, you can put the values into an object[,] and set the value of A1:J1 in one go, which is a little faster.

Comment: +1 for " you can put the values into an object[,] and set the value of A1:J1 in one go, which is a little faster."  This is MUCH faster if you are writing multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

The Excel `get_range` did not work for me.
What did work is this:

```
Range c1 = workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, 3]];
c1.Value = "name";
```